# Logcar Error: addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapterview

I'm doing an application for Android and if I click a "Generate" button, it generates a list that each row has an image, textView, and 2 buttons. The number of list is random, more than 30. Using layout inflater, I want to add a child view to main.xml layout. but when I click the 'Generate' button, Logcat error is occured.

**06-08 05:33:19.340: E/AndroidRuntime(853): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView**

I don't understand what is an "AdapterView" and how I fix this error.

Here is my code.

```
package com.android.listtest1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ListTest1Activity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    int[] images = new int[50];
    TextView tv1, tv2;
    Button btn_gen, btn_clear;
    Button btn_phone, btn_sms;
    ImageView img;
    ArrayAdapter<String> list;
    LinearLayout new_linear;
    ListView listview;
    Intent intent1;
    int list_cnt = 0;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        btn_gen = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_gen);
        btn_clear = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_clear);

        btn_gen.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_clear.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if( v == btn_gen){

            int i, j, rand, cnt_rand;
            for(i=0;i<50;i++){
                images[i] = i;
            }
            images[0] = R.drawable.c1992_1;
            images[1] = R.drawable.c1992_2;
            images[2] = R.drawable.c1993;
            images[3] = R.drawable.c1994;
            images[4] = R.drawable.c1995_1;
            images[5] = R.drawable.c1995_2;
            images[6] = R.drawable.c1996_1;
            images[7] = R.drawable.c1996_2;
            images[8] = R.drawable.c1998;
            images[9] = R.drawable.c2000;
            images[10] = R.drawable.c2001;
            images[11] = R.drawable.c2002;
            images[12] = R.drawable.c2004;
            images[13] = R.drawable.c2005;
            images[14] = R.drawable.c2007_1;
            images[15] = R.drawable.c2008;
            images[16] = R.drawable.c2009_1;
            images[17] = R.drawable.c2009_2;
            images[18] = R.drawable.c2009_3;
            images[19] = R.drawable.c2010_1;
            images[20] = R.drawable.d2005_1;
            images[21] = R.drawable.d2005_2;
            images[22] = R.drawable.d2010_2;
            images[23] = R.drawable.d2010_3;
            images[24] = R.drawable.d2010_4;
            images[25] = R.drawable.i01;
            images[26] = R.drawable.i2010_1;
            images[27] = R.drawable.alien_1;
            images[28] = R.drawable.alien_2;
            images[29] = R.drawable.balloon;
            images[30] = R.drawable.bear;
            images[31] = R.drawable.beaver;
            images[32] = R.drawable.birthdaycake;
            images[33] = R.drawable.chocolatecake;
            images[34] = R.drawable.david;
            images[35] = R.drawable.davinci;
            images[36] = R.drawable.dragon;
            images[37] = R.drawable.earth;
            images[38] = R.drawable.fireworks1;
            images[39] = R.drawable.fireworks2;
            images[40] = R.drawable.fish;
            images[41] = R.drawable.frog1;
            images[42] = R.drawable.frog2;
            images[43] = R.drawable.hand;
            images[44] = R.drawable.leaf;
            images[45] = R.drawable.monkey1;
            images[46] = R.drawable.women;
            images[47] = R.drawable.sun;
            images[48] = R.drawable.rose;
            images[49] = R.drawable.rabbit;

            String str_name, str_desc;          
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            new_linear = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null);           
            img = (ImageView)new_linear.findViewById(R.id.img);
            tv1 = (TextView)new_linear.findViewById(R.id.name);
            tv2 = (TextView)new_linear.findViewById(R.id.desc);
            str_name = tv1.getText().toString();
            str_desc = tv2.getText().toString();    
            //List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for(i = 0; i < 50; )
            {
                rand = ((int)(Math.random() * 50)) + 1;             

                cnt_rand = ((int)(Math.random() * 100)) + 30;
                for(j = 0; j < cnt_rand; j++){
                    img.setImageResource(images[rand]);
                    tv1.setText(str_name+Integer.toString(j));
                    tv2.setText(str_desc+Integer.toString(j));
                    listview.addView(new_linear);
                }
            }

        }else if( v == btn_clear){

        }
    }
}
```

this is main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_info"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/list_info"

        android:layout_gravity="center" android:textSize="20dp"/>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_gen"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/btn_gen" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp" 
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"/> 

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_clear"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/btn_clear" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is add.xml what I want to add as a each row of a list.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/c1992_1" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"             
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp" 
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:text="11"
        />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/desc"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" 
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:text="11"
        />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_phone"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/phone" android:layout_marginTop="25dp"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_sms"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/sms" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Please explain in detail that I can understand. (I am real first programmer)

thanks for everything in advanced !

Answer (score 2):

An [`AdapterView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html) is a view whose children are determined by an [`Adapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html). The [`ListView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) is a subclass of [`AdapterView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html) that is populated by a [`ListAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html). You can take a look at the ["Hello, Views: List View"](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html) tutorial to understand how to use the [`ListView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html).

In your case, you need to create a custom adapter which will override the `getView` method and return the custom view that contains the instance of the inflated add.xml.

Comment: Thanks Rajesh, but which type of listView I can use? actually in main screen there is no list before click "Generate" button. and the add.xml has 3 type of views. I don' know how I create ListAdapter.

Comment: There are a lot of tutorials available on using custom adapters (like [this](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429&q=customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter) and [this](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/) ), search and you will find. You can use the `images` array as the backing store for your adapter and populate it in the `onClick` of the "Generate" button. Do your research and try out things.